# How to filter or query an array made using {} in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

this is the first question I've ever posted on here so I apologize if I did something incorrectly.

I've got a sheet that I used to keep track of the release dates of various products. I want to be able to filter all of these products based on whether or not their release date is the current day. However, I'm having trouble using `FILTER` or `QUERY` to do this. After doing some research I've learned how to "stack" the list of products on top of each other as an array to then filter, but I can't quite get it to work. I had it to where it would work if rows in both of the sections I was testing in had a match, but if one didn't then the whole formula returned an error. This was also only using a few rows for each section, where ideally I'd want to look at the entire section.

Here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sP26Ptuv8eBqLLZoAah49XjrwavcNSMIlyWwG-dBq1A/edit#gid=879002581

And this is the formula I'm using in cell B3:
`=FILTER({F3:H; J3:L; N3:P; R3:T; V3:X; Z3:AB}, D3:D = 9/20/2019)`

But this gives me an error saying it expected a different amount of rows, which makes sense but I don't know how to fix. Specifically, it gives me this error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 654. column count: 1. Actual row count: 109, column count: 1.

I've also tried using `QUERY` but I don't know how to select what I'm looking for. I tried using both Col1, Col2, etc. and A, B, etc. but it kept giving me errors no matter what I tried.

Between this error and the one I mentioned previously, I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be like:

```
=FILTER({F3:H; J3:L; N3:P; R3:T; V3:X; Z3:AB}, 
        {H3:H; L3:L; P3:P; T3:T; X3:X; AB3:AB}=DATE(2019, 9, 20))
```

[image]

---

then for today you can use:

```
=FILTER({F3:H; J3:L; N3:P; R3:T; V3:X; Z3:AB}, 
        {H3:H; L3:L; P3:P; T3:T; X3:X; AB3:AB}=TODAY())
```

---

and `QUERY` would be:

```
=QUERY({F3:H; J3:L; N3:P; R3:T; V3:X; Z3:AB}, 
 "where Col3 = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]